# MJM mail creation process optimization

Tags: mailjet, mjml

I must be missing something in our mail development process.

We are developing a complex email template, with many vars. Here is our actual process which leads to mistakes

1. Write/develop template using mjml editor (with complex for, if, etc.)
2. Get generated html from mjml (still using editor)
3. Upload mjml & html to mailjet using API (v3)
4. Send a mail with vars using this template through API (v3.1)
5. Verify integration & vars parsing by reading the received mail & templateError mail if received

The problem is that we see some delay between the moment we update template to mailjet and the moment it is taken into account by mailjet. We often receive a mail with a precedent version of template so debugging is really hard.

Is there a way to get template processing with vars locally, maybe without having the template being sent by email?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like mailjet is planning to develop a /render endpoint which will be able to render the vars (from mjml.slack.com). Waiting forward to this.